# Save uploaded resume using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm exploring an API, but I'm stuck on how to upload a resume and save it using javascript/jQuery

Here is a [link](http://apiv1.recruiterbox.com/backend_api.html#apply-for-a-opening) to the API, if you want to take a look.
The end goal is to have the resume loaded in an object. I only care about loading the uploaded file/resume

Here is the expected output:

```
let payload = {
    "fields": [{
        "key" : "resume", "value": {
            "encoded_data" : "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=",
            "file_name" : "resume.txt"
        }
    }],
    "source" : "new website"
}
```

Here is the structure of the HTML file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="json-response">
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Application form</h1>
    </div>
    <form action="#" class="applicantForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="Resume">Resume <span>*</span></label>
          <input class="form-control" type="file" name="Resume">
        </div> 
      </div>
      <button class="submit" type="submit">Apply Now</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    const ApplyOpeningPayloadBuilder = function() {
        let payload = {
            "fields": [],
            "source" : "new website"
        };
        return {
            withKeyValue: function(key, value) {
                let param = {};
                param.key = key;
                param.value = value;
                payload.fields.push(param);
                return this;
            },
            withFile: function(key, encoded_data, filename) {
                let value = {};
                value.encoded_data = encoded_data;
                value.file_name = filename;
                this.withKeyValue(key, value);
                return this;
            },
            build: function() {
                return payload;
            }
        }
    }

    let encoded_file = "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=";
    $('.applicantForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let apply_for_an_opening_payload_builder = new ApplyOpeningPayloadBuilder();
        apply_for_an_opening_payload_builder.withFile("resume", encoded_file, this.value);
        let payload = apply_for_an_opening_payload_builder.build();
        console.log("Log uploaded resume:", payload);
   });
})
```

Comment: You did not define the function `withKeyValue`. NB: I fixed the indentation of your code. It would be nice if you kept a proper indentation of your code when you edit your question further.

Comment: @trincot what do you mean I didn't define the `withKeyValue`? can you explain a little more or provide a brief example

Comment: What is the call `this.withKeyValue(key, value);` supposed to do? I don't see the definition of `withKeyValue` in your code?

Comment: @trincot I complete forgot to paste it in. I just updated the code

Comment: I fixed the indentation (again).

Comment: `fields` is never defined as a property of `payload`, so the `push` will fail...

Comment: @trincot I updated the code with `fields`.

Comment: `this.value` is going to be undefined. Did you intend `this.Resume.value`?

Comment: @trincot why would it be `this.resume.value`? I placed `this.value` as a place holder because I wasn't sure on what value to place there

Comment: Because your form does not have a `value` property, while your `input` has one, which is the file name? Did you ever test this code?

Comment: @trincot I did test the code, with the current code it saves a file that reads `hello world`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207005/discussion-between-bruce-and-trincot).

Comment: That's great, but your are not in chat :/